# Capture screenshot using htmlunitdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, htmlunit, capture, htmlunit-driver

How can I capture a screenshot using `HtmlUnitDriver`? I found that i can capture when I use `FirefoxDriver` but I don't want to use Firefox. So, please let me know how to capture images using `HtmlUnitDriver`.

I googled but none of the solutions I found are working for me. Please help!

Comment: no solutions @Robot ?

Answer (score 2):

Flyingsaucer is a java library which lets you take screenshots of a webpage headlessly (without opening the page in a browser). The following code will capture a screenshot of the entire page resized into an image called "screenshot.png". The number 1024 specifies the width of the output screenshot. Find the libraries here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer

```
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.simple.Graphics2DRenderer;

public class RenderPage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
             String address = "http://www.w3.org";
             BufferedImage buff = Graphics2DRenderer.renderToImageAutoSize(address, 1024);
             ImageIO.write(buff, "png", new File("screenshot.png"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

You can also use the method Graphics2DRenderer.renderToImage(address,1024,1024); to define your own size of screenshot.

You'll find that the screenshots look as if they were rendered on a phone. I don't know why this is, but I'm guessing that you can change Flyingsaucer's browser version somewhere to emulate the page on different browsers.

One more thing is that this code won't screenshot www.google.com but apparently this type of error can be solved by tidying up the page source with a library called JTidy.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score -1):

HtmlUnitDriver is GUI-less.
see: [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1361)

Maybe you can use the following:

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(newRectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/screenshot.png"));
```

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)

Comment: and... how the HtmlUnit page could be taken as screenshot? @Storm